# Scichart Legend won't consume mouse activity

Tags: wpf, scichart

I have a realtime scrolling chart with a legend. The legend works as expected but when the legend is clicked the mouse click propagates to the Scichart surface below, this is problematic as the surface is also setup to zoom and pan. When a series IsVisible is toggled through the legend the surface will also change to pan or zoom from the mouse activity.

From the [How To Add Mouse Interaction to Scichart](https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17228/0/how-to-add-mouse-interaction-to-scichart) article it explains ChartModifier Precedence (Handled Events) in this section "...the first modifier that handles an event marks it as e.Handled. Subsequent modifiers will not receive the event". This doesn't seem to be the case, the LegendModifier gets handled but so does the ZoomPanModifier.

```
<SciChart:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
<SciChart:ModifierGroup>
    <SciChart:LegendModifier x:Name="mainLegend" GetLegendDataFor="SelectedSeries" 
                                MouseEnter="mainLegend_MouseEnter" 
                                MouseLeave="mainLegend_MouseLeave" 
                                PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="mainLegend_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                MouseLeftButtonDown="mainLegend_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                ReceiveHandledEvents="False"/>

    <SciChart:MouseWheelZoomModifier x:Name="mouseWheelZoomMod" XyDirection="XDirection" ReceiveHandledEvents="False"/>
    <SciChart:ZoomPanModifier x:Name="zoomPanMod" ExecuteOn="MouseLeftButton" ReceiveHandledEvents="False"/>
</SciChart:ModifierGroup>
```

I've ensured ReceiveHandledEvents="False" for all the modifiers. Also tried an assortment of events on the legendmodifier: MouseLeftButtonDown, PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, MouseEnter and MouseLeave but none of these ever fire.

Is it possible to stop the mouse activity for the Legend propagating to the surface below/other modifiers?